# Magento install complains about missing InnoDB when it is available

Tags: php, mysql, magento, innodb

During installation, Magento produces the following error:

> Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.

I've fixed all the dependancies for Magento, and double checked with MySQL on the command line using SHOW ENGINES and definitely have InnoDB available (also the default storage engine).

This isn't an issue about access to MySQL config which others might have seen on their install.

Note: This is running on a Mac Pro (with a simple hosts DNS rewrite for the domain name I am developing for).

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: 5.6.10 - literally downloaded it about 20 mins ago

Comment: Just to confirm, have just created the following test table:

+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mystoragetest | CREATE TABLE `mystoragetest` (
  `tester` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+-----

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Line 59 of the file `app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php`

Replace:

```
public function supportEngine()
{
    $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
        ->fetchPairs('SHOW VARIABLES');
    return (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') ? false : true;
}
```

with this:

```
public function supportEngine()
{
    $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
        ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
    return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'NO');
}
```

Comment: Nice one, spent the last hour trying to figure this out

Comment: bad idea to edit core code, check answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16870033/299774

Comment: This change is part of the master branch at magento2, so I don't think it's going to be an issue! https://github.com/magento/magento2

Comment: what if it doesn't help with the magento 1.9.2.0 as the code update mentioned here is already fixed in this version

Answer (score 20):

Or don't do a core-hack! You should override the Installer-Model softly before Installation:

Paste this in your `app/code/local/Company/InstallBugfix/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_InstallBugfix>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_InstallBugfix>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <installbugfix>
                <class>Company_InstallBugfix_Model</class>
            </installbugfix>
            <install>
                <rewrite>
                    <installer_db_mysql4>Company_InstallBugfix_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4</installer_db_mysql4>
                </rewrite>
            </install>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And following in `app/code/local/Company/InstallBugfix/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php`:

```
<?php
class Company_InstallBugfix_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4 extends Mage_Install_Model_Installer_Db_Mysql4
{
    /**
     * Check InnoDB support
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportEngine()
    {
        $supportsEngine = parent::supportEngine();
        if ($supportsEngine) {
            return true;
        }
        $variables = $this
                     ->_getConnection()
                     ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
        return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'NO');
    }
}
```

And enable the extension. The advantage is, that the old validation is still correct, if the mysql-version is older.

Comment: Re "Don't do a core hack" ~ True ... however, the core dev team should be responsible for backporting compat...

Answer (score 5):

## ver 1.9.1.0 downloader.php

Putting this up for anyone thats using the `downloader.php` currently bundled in the `1.9.1.0` installer.

If you're happy that your MySQL Database does support InnoDB (It's the DEFAULT) in later versions. You can safely edit the file to remove the check and all the download to take place.

```
    /**
     * Check availabe InnoDB on database.
     *
     * @return Magento_Downloader_Validator
     */
    protected function _checkDbInnoDb()
    {
        if (!$this->_connection) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->addMessage('Database server supports InnoDB storage engine');
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug was fixed in Magento CE 1.8, so just use the lines above for CE \leq 1.7

Comment: Given it's just the `protected function _checkDbInnoDb()` function that still throws this error in `downloader.php` If you're confident your Database does support InnoDB - You can safely comment out the check.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function supportEngine()
{
    $variables  = $this->_getConnection()->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
    return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'NO');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue and the only way it worked was when I changed Line 59 of the file *app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php* from:

```
public function supportEngine()
{
    $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
        ->fetchPairs('SHOW VARIABLES');
    return (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') ? false : true;
}
```

With:

```
public function supportEngine()
    {
        $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
            ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
        return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'YES');
    }
```

And I didn't find it anywhere so if you are struggling I guarantee this will solve it.

Answer (score -2):

Line 59 of the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php

Replace:

```
public function supportEngine()
 {
    $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
        ->fetchPairs('SHOW VARIABLES');
    return (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') ? false : true;
}
```

with this:

```
public function supportEngine()
{
 /*   
     $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
        ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
     return (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') ? false : true; 
*/
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: why do you bother to change the `fecthPairs` line if you are returning **true** anyway just after?

Comment: This is a bad idea, maybe even dangerous. You're suggesting we pretend InnoDB is always enabled, rather than actually checking.