# Install Magento 1.7.2 on Win 8 -What is the cause of failing?

Tags: apache, magento, windows-8, installation, wamp

Im trying to setup Magento 1.7.2 on Windows 8. Here are the products & versions that I Am trying to setup:

Magento version is 1.7.2. 
Wamp php 5.4.16 
Wamp apache 2.4.4 
mysql 5.6.12
OS: Windows 8

PROBLEM:
**The installation does not continue in the point where you declare the DB , the root user and password.
The page refreshes without any warning or error !!! Ofcourse the credentials are correct(db name, root user etc**

Additionally the collation of the empty magento db is ut8_general_ci
url_rewrite its enabled on apache

Any help would be highly respected and appreciated… 
**Thanks in advance.**

UPDATE

I got an error in Firefox(Chrome didnt show it) 
**Database server does not support the Innodb storage engine but my Mysql runs and accepts InnoDb storage engines**. Somebody please ?

Comment: Did you check this post http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/279012/#t385496

Comment: Just found an error in Firefox(Chrome didnt show it) Database server does not support the Innodb storage engine but my Mysql runs and accepts InnoDb storage engines. Somebody please ?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284498/innodb-working-still-showing-database-server-does-not-support-innodb-storage-e

Comment: Thank you muhammedv that was it!!!

Comment: How can I credit you for your correct answer mate?

Comment: @kost Tick or up-vote the article that he pointed you to that solved your issue.