# Update local MYSQL version OSX

Tags: php, mysql, macos, magento

I'm trying to upgrade my local version (on mac) of mysql in order to meet the requirements to work with Magento.

IM using the magento-check.php and it's saying my mysql version isn't up to date. Under failed it says "you need MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)"

However if I run

```
<?php printf("MySQL server version: %s\n", mysql_get_server_info()); ?>
```

I get MySQL server version: 5.6.15.

Any ideas on wants going on here?

Comment: What does `mysql_get_client_info()` return?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas on what's going on here?

Assuming you're using the [Magento Check script located here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento), take a look at how Magento performs its `mysql` tests

```
#File: magento-check.php
preg_match('/[0-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/', shell_exec('mysql -V'), $version);
```

They're running a `shell_exec('mysql -V')` shell command via PHP to view the version of mysql you're using.  My guess if your OS X system doesn't have the `mysql` client in it's path, so this script thinks you have no MySQL installed.

Using the CLI client to check mysql versions is a little bananas — but I guess it works enough  Your version of MySQL looks fine.  The only problem you might run into is if you're using an older version of Magento, the installer's [INNODB detection is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443448/magento-complains-missing-innodb-when-it-is-available) for MySQL 5.6 and above.  This bug has been fixed in the latest 1.x community edition releases.