# Installing magento - Database server does not support InnoDB storage engine

Tags: php, mysql, magento, wampserver

I'm trying to install Magento on my local server (WampServer 2.4), using magento [downloader](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download), but I get following error while cheking database connection in first step of this installatoin.

> Database server does not support InnoDB storage engine

it maybe because of the mysql version which is 5.6.12, but I couldn't downgrade it. also when I change the my.ini file to enable InnoDB engine as follow mysql service didn't start.

```
# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

also here is the result of running show engines command:

[image]

I also try install using full release of it, but I get following error:

> Warning: require(app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\wamp\www\magento\install.php on line 125
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app/Mage.php'
>   (include_path='C:\wamp\www\magento;.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento\install.php on line 125 Call Stack

also it didn't contain `app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php` so I couldn't try [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443448/magento-install-complains-about-missing-innodb-when-it-is-available) in similar question.

could anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded the package from Magento, 1.9.1 definitely includes the file app\code\core\Mage\Install\Model\Installer\Db\Mysql4.php - so I would expect that this hasn't extracted correctly on your system.  You should see that 1.9.1 actually already includes the fix you mention (change from `have_innodb`).

Comment: Cool - if you're happy that this solves the issue, please feel free to mark this answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with your edits to `my.ini` is you have not taken into account where WAMPServer installs itself. Assuming you installed WAMPServer on C:\ then change the `my.ini` like this :-

```
# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data
innodb_log_arch_dir = C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Note the use of unix `/` and not the dos \ and also the correct file paths to where MYSQL is actually installed!

If you installed in a different location then amend as required

Comment: I changed the path, but stil Mysql service didn't start!

Comment: Well what is in the mysql error log, or the Windows Event Viewer from MYSQL